# Is there any command line windows program available to get all hardware resources of PC?

Tags: windows, command-line

I'm seeking for a command line program to get all hardware types of a computer, including their brands. For example :

> Hard disk: 250 GB WD
>  CPU: G2020 2.5 GHz intell 
> ....

Answer (score 2):

Almost all computer specs are available via WMI queries. These can be run from the command line using [**`wmic`**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx).

For example, to get hard drive data you could type:

```
wmic DISKDRIVE
```

To get the GPU info, run:

```
wmic PATH Win32_VideoController GET Description,PNPDeviceID
```

You'll need to look up the exact WMI query for each hardware component you're interested in, but a quick google search should find you the necessary info for almost anything you need.

Answer (score 1):

[CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) is a program capable of gathering a great deal of information about system. I has a GUI interface but it can also be run from the command line using the `-txt=report.txt` command line option. This will cause it to place it's generated report in a text file.

Answer (score 1):

MSINFO32 sounds will do the trick

```
Msinfo32 [/?] [/pch] [/nfo Path] [/report Path] [/computer ComputerName] [/showcategories] [/category categoryID] [/categories categoryID]
```

Look here: [Microsoft Knowledgebase](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300887)